# IOS swift how to know when activityViewController has been successfully used

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a tableView that utilizes the `UIActivityViewController` so users can share content on other 3rd party networks Facebook, twitter, text message etc. I have a function called `IncreaseShareByOne()` and it's purpose is to count the number of times that something has been shared . My problem is that right now that function fires of every time the `UIActivityViewController` is clicked . Is there someway that I can find out if a user really shared something so that  I can use that function correctly ? becomes sometimes you open the `UIActivityViewController` and decide not to share anything so I want to catch and not use that function. I am new to swift and am using version 3 .

```
func sharedShareAction(controller: UIViewController, sender: UIButton) {

    controller.present(activityViewController,animated: true,completion: nil)
    IncreaseShareByOne()
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a completion handler to your `UIActivityViewController`. In the completion handler, check whether the user submitted using the `completed` value.  You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
func sharedShareAction(controller: UIViewController, sender: UIButton) {

    controller.present(activityViewController,animated: true, completion: nil)

    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, completed, items, error in
            if !completed {
                // handle task not completed
                return
            }
            IncreaseShareByOne()
        }
}
```

Check the [API docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontrollercompletionwithitemshandler) for more info.